# How do I use Bgl?

Tags: python, add-on, opengl

So my question is:
I understand nothing about openGl api, that's super confuse to me, Where do I start?

I did get that I need to append a callback to a draw handler and remove it to enable/disable my drawing funcion by seeing examples.

But how I use Bgl library, it's a wrapper to openGL?
Its a blender's? implementation of openGL?

How do I read the open GL docs?

And most important:
How do I convert from screen to 3D space and vice versa?